# Reading and writing an INI file

Tags: vbscript, ini, hta

I have been toying with the below script to be able to read settings for use with my HTA (creating a game launcher).

Here is my current HTA:

http://pastebin.com/skTgqs5X

It doesn't quite work, it complains of the `WScript` object being required. While I understand `Echo` will not work like that in a HTA I am having trouble modifying the code so it will work. Even just removing all `Echo` references it still has an issue with `objOrgIni` on line 200 of the below code (with the `WScript` references removed):

http://pastebin.com/pGjv4Gh1

I don't even need that level of error checking as the INI will exist etc, I just need a simple way to read from and write to an INI in my scripting. Any help you guys can give me in achieving that would be great, it's a little advanced for me just yet, but I'd love an explanation as to why it fails.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the hole code of your HTA and explain more your issue , and in which line you got the error.

Comment: Done, thanks, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

There is no easy way to use INI files with VBScript. You'd have to write the functionality yourself or find some existing code that does it.

But do you really need an INI specifically or just a way to save settings? You could just keep all of your settings in a `Dictionary` object and serialize it as needed.

For example, here are two functions -- `LoadSettings` and `SaveSettings` -- that do just that.

```
Public Function LoadSettings(strFile)

    Set LoadSettings = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim strLine, a
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If Not .FileExists(strFile) Then Exit Function
        With .OpenTextFile(strFile)
            Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                strLine = Trim(.ReadLine())
                If InStr(strLine, "=") > 0 Then
                    a = Split(strLine, "=")
                    LoadSettings.Add a(0), a(1)
                End If
            Loop
        End With
    End With

End Function

Sub SaveSettings(d, strFile)

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(strFile, True)
        Dim k
        For Each k In d
            .WriteLine k & "=" & d(k)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Imagine you had the following settings file saved at `c:\settings.txt`:

```
Count=2
Name=Obama
```

You'd use the functions above like this:

```
Const SETTINGS_FILE = "c:\settings.txt"

Dim Settings
Set Settings = LoadSettings(SETTINGS_FILE)

' Show all settings...
WScript.Echo Join(Settings.Keys, ", ")         ' => Count, Name

' Query a setting...
WScript.Echo Settings("Count")                 ' => 2

' Update a setting...
Settings("Count") = Settings("Count") + 1

' Add a setting...
Settings("New") = 1

' Save settings...
SaveSettings Settings, SETTINGS_FILE
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you for that, I guess I just want INI because I eventually will convert it to an exe, however your approach seems to achieve the basic goal itself. Other reason is there will be settings stored for the game itself, and for the launcher. I wanted a way to seperate them and the structure of an ini file allows that. I'd like to see an example of both options if possible, but I'm not at a proficiency level enough to be able to modify the script I copied into my file yet.

Comment: In addition, how would I use those in a string output fashion, I currently use the below as wscript.echo doesn't function in a HTA:

    Function Output(Echo)
    ' Output status
    Document.Write("<div class='messages'>" & Echo & "</div>") 
    End Function
    Call Output(Echo)

I don't seem to be able to set the result of Join(Settings.Keys, ", ")  as a variable for later use, it throws up errors.

Comment: What errors? The result of `Join(Settings.Keys, ", ")` is just a string.

Comment: Doing it like this: 

    Set Echo = Join(Settings.Keys, ", ")Function Output(Echo)
        
    ' Output status
    Document.Write("<div class='messages'>" & Echo & "</div>") 
    
    End Function
    
    Call Output(Echo) causes the following error: Object required "[string: "Count, Name, bgAudio"]" bgAudio was a setting I was testing out.

Comment: You use `Set` for objects, not intrinsic types (strings, numbers, bools). `Echo = Join(Settings.Keys, ", ")`.

Comment: I realise I am being quite vague with the question, but can you re-purpose an ini read and write function to work in a HTA so that others looking for the same can also benefit from it? I understand and appreciate your advice re: the dictionary but I feel it's solvable by you amazing folks.