# How to loop a 2 array using a for each... next loop?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, vbscript, foreach

I have this simple basic code of VBScript using **For Each...Next Loop**

```vb
<%
Dim cars(2)
cars(0)="Volvo"
cars(1)="Saab"
cars(2)="BMW"

For Each x In cars
   response.write(x & "<br>")
Next
%>
```

Output:

```
Volvo
Saab
BMW
```

I would like to ask for a help on how to loop if you have two array.

For example:

```vb
Dim cars(2), fruits(2)

cars(0)="Volvo"
cars(1)="Saab"
cars(2)="BMW"

fruits(0)="Apple"
fruits(1)="Orange"
fruits(2)="Banana"
```

What my expectation output is:

```
Volvo Apple
Saab Orange
BMW Banana
```

Please also consider that the 2 array matches its number, (e.g Volvo and Apple is both **(0)** )

I tried to search for this on the internet but no topic for this one. A big appreciation for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `For` instead of `For Each` and output the array at the same index in both arrays. You have to pick one of the arrays to use `UBound()` off, just make surwe both arrays have the same number of element or you will end up with `Sub Script out of Range` errors.

```vb
Dim cars: cars = Array("Volvo", "Saab", "BMW")
Dim fruits: fruits = Array("Apple", "Orange", "Banana")

Dim i: i = 0

For i = 0 To UBound(cars)
  Call Response.Write(cars(i) & " " & fruits(i))
Next
```

Output:

```
Volvo Apple
Saab Orange
BMW Banana
```

Another approach which avoids the issues with `Sub Script out of Range` errors is to use a Multi Dimensional Array.

```vb
Dim things(2, 1)
Dim i: i = 0

things(0, 0) = "Volvo"
things(0, 1) = "Apple"
things(1, 0) = "Saab"
things(1, 1) = "Orange"
things(2, 0) = "BMW"
things(2, 1) = "Banana"

For i = 0 To UBound(things, 1)
  Call Response.Write(things(x, 0) & " " & things(x, 1))
Next
```

Output:

```
Volvo Apple
Saab Orange
BMW Banana
```

Another approach is almost an amalgamation of the first two, it uses a Single Dimension Array but nests Single Dimension Arrays inside it.

```vb
Dim things(2)

things(0) = Array("Volvo", "Apple")
things(1) = Array("Saab", "Orange")
things(2) = Array("BMW", "Banana")

For Each thing In things
  Call Response.Write(thing(0) & " " & thing(1))
Next
```

Output:

```
Volvo Apple
Saab Orange
BMW Banana
```

Comment: Hi Lankymart, thank you so much, it works! Just one more thing, do you have idea on how these array variable be possible to put on ini file? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Djamille May be this will help - [Reading and writing an INI file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31149246/692942)

Comment: Sorry @Lankymart, actually, your answer is more helpful and i learned more about array on this specially UBound, please don't misunderstand, this is just a late upvote, thank you so much for your great help!

Comment: @Djamille it's fine, just struggling to understand you logic behind accepting the answer in the other question. Also try not to post too many duplicate question, 5 minutes after seeing your questions I googled using `site:stackoverflow.com` and found a duplicate in seconds that would probably help you. Understand you are new to the site, so maybe take a look at [ask] to help you out with [so] etiquette in future.