# How to put a 2 array in config (.ini) file?

Tags: arrays, loops, vbscript, config, ini

I have this simple basic code of VBScript.

```js
Dim cars: cars = Array("Volvo", "Saab", "BMW")
Dim fruits: fruits = Array("Apple", "Orange", "Banana")

Dim i: i = 0

For i = 0 To UBound(cars)
  Call Response.Write(cars(i) & " " & fruits(i))
Next
```

Output:

```js
Volvo Apple
Saab Orange
BMW Banana
```

I want to put all the variables in a config **.ini file** in a way that the array variable is still in match. (e.g. **Volvo** and **Apple** for **Volvo Apple**) Anyone know or have an idea to do it?

I tried to search for this on the internet but no topic for this one. A big appreciation for the answer.

Comment: Just look at the [structure of an INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Example) and write out the content accordingly, there is nothing special about it, [I've already shown you how you can output the content of the arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38394720/692942). It is now up to you to build the INI format.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array use a disconnected recordset. They can be saved to file in binary or xml format.

This stores lines in a file then sorts the recordset on line number and writes it back.

```
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Dim LineCount
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With rs
    .Fields.Append "LineNumber", 4 
    .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
    .Open
    LineCount = 0
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        LineCount = LineCount + 1
        .AddNew
        .Fields("LineNumber").value = LineCount
        .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
        .UpDate
    Loop
    .Sort = "LineNumber DESC"
    Do While not .EOF
        Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo file.vbs < %windir%\win.ini
```

And from Help for a recordset

> Save Method Saves the Recordset in a file or Stream object.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
>  recordset.Save Destination, PersistFormat
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> Destination  Optional. A Variant that represents the complete path
> name of the file where the Recordset is to be saved, or a reference to
> a Stream object.
>
> PersistFormat  Optional. A PersistFormatEnum value
> that specifies the format in which the Recordset is to be saved (XML
> or ADTG). The default value is adPersistADTG.  Remarks

Comment: Hi Noodles, what .ini file looks like? This is the most important. Thank you.

Comment: You just save and load it.

Comment: They want to output an Array to an INI format not read an INI file into the script. The benefit of using a disconnected recordset is negligible at best.