# How to put a 2 array variables in config (.ini) file?

Tags: arrays, loops, vbscript, ftp, ini

**I have this VBScript that send specific files to FTP based on the file name.**

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objMyFile, objShell, strFTPScriptFileName, strFilePut
Dim strLocalFolderName, strScriptFolder, strFTPServerName, strLoginID, strReportPath
Dim strPassword, strFTPServerFolder

Dim objArg, strIniFilePath, oShell

Dim i: i = 0

'Locates the INI File
Set objArg = WScript.Arguments
strIniFilePath = objArg(0)

'Gets FTP UserId and Password
strLocalFolderName = ReadIni(strIniFilePath,"FTP","LocalFolderName")
strFTPServerName = ReadIni(strIniFilePath,"FTP","FTPServerName")
strLoginID = ReadIni(strIniFilePath,"FTP","LoginID")
strPassword = ReadIni(strIniFilePath,"FTP","Password")

strFTPScriptFileName = ReadIni(strIniFilePath,"FTP","FTPScriptFileName")

strReportPath= Array("/davaoccc" , "/calambaccc" , "/cebuccc")
strFilePut= Array("0970*.txt" , "0979*.txt" , "0983*.txt")


Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (objFSO.FileExists(strFTPScriptFileName)) Then
objFSO.DeleteFile (strFTPScriptFileName)
End If

For i = 0 To UBound(strReportPath)
Set objMyFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFTPScriptFileName, True)
objMyFile.WriteLine ("open " & strFTPServerName)
objMyFile.WriteLine (strLoginID)
objMyFile.WriteLine (strPassword)
objMyFile.WriteLine ("cd " & strReportPath(i))
objMyFile.WriteLine ("bin")
objMyFile.WriteLine ("lcd " & strLocalFolderName)
objMyFile.WriteLine ("prompt off")
objMyFile.WriteLine ("mput " & strFilePut(i))
objMyFile.WriteLine ("disconnect")
objMyFile.WriteLine ("bye")
objMyFile.Close

'Execute the FTP script. 
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run "ftp -s:" & Chr(34) & strFTPScriptFileName & Chr(34), , True 

next
```

**This is the .ini file**

```
[FTP]
LocalFolderName=D:\Output\
FTPServerName=172.22.11.220
LoginID=user
Password=1234
FTPScriptFileName=D:\FTP_Log.txt
```

As you can see, the values of the variables is in the .ini file (hardcoded value should be in the .ini files) but except for the two variables: **strReportPath**, **strFilePut**

There are multiple destination folder in the FTP, and different files based on the filename (files starts with 0970, 0979, 0983) in which, this VBScripts successfully sends. But I am having a hard time on how to put a 2 array variables in config ini file in a way that the array variable is still in match. (e.g. /davaoccc for 0970, /calambaccc for 0979, /cebuccc for 0983)

Anyone know or have an idea to do it?

I tried to search for this on the internet but no topic for this one. A big appreciation for the answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Put array elements in a comma separated list, then write some VBscript to parse these values.

```
strReportPath = /davaoccc,/calambaccc,/cebuccc

strFilePut= 0970*.txt,0979*.txt,0983*.txt
```

I assume all values are read as text, so you can drop the string quotes.

Comment: Hi Seth, i put the array elements in the ini file as what you've said, when i run the VBScript it says a runtime error that **type mismatch: UBound** , what do you mean by **write some VBscript to parse these values** . Thank you so much.

Comment: You going to do that `strReportPath` needs to be a string `strReportPath = "/davaoccc,/calambaccc,/cebuccc"` as does `strFilePut`.

Comment: This answer is pointless, they already have the values as Arrays what does storing them as a comma separated list achieve? You'd have to call `Split()` anyway to convert that comma separated list to an array ?? Why did you accept this @Djamille?

Comment: @Lankymart did you read his code? He had the arrays defined in VBscript and was asking how to include the arrays in the .ini file. As far as I know, .ini doesn't support "array" types, it's not like json or xml. Therefore, it will simply read the whole line as a string. Thus, he'll need to split the line. Maybe I misunderstood his question, but he accepted it so I couldn't have been too far off. Either that or he's sending me pity points! :)

Comment: @SethFoster pity points I'm afraid, plus I didn't need to read the question as [I showed them how to read the arrays in the first place](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38394720/692942).